# Page jumps to top when scrollbar reaches bottom safari iphone

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm working on a web application that was not built with responsive design, so the mobile experience is not very good for users. Nonetheless, users still use the site on mobile devices. When a particular page in the app is rendered on a mobile device, a vertical scroll bar appears, which seems to be totally normal (viewing the same page in a desktop browser also has a vertical scroll bar). The issue is that when the user on the mobile device tries to scroll to the bottom to press the submit button, the page jumps back to the very top. More specifically, the user touches and drags the screen so that the bottom of the page comes into view, and as soon as they lift their finger from the screen, the page jumps back to the top, preventing them from being able to press the submit button because it becomes hidden from view. I've hooked up my iPhone 5s to my Mac and used Desktop Safari to set up remote debugging. That hasn't helped much yet. I noticed that changing the device orientation makes the issue go away. More specifically, the issue happens in both portrait and landscape orientation. However, if you load the page in one orientation and then switch to the other orientation, the issue seems to go away. I also noticed that setting an explicit height on one of the container divs in the CSS seems to fix the issue, despite the CSS rule being ultimately overridden by the browser (I think). When I set the height, though, the page renders a little differently because the content seems more zoomed out and no vertical scroll bar appears.

I've searched around the web for a while and have not found anything useful. I found two SO posts about similar issues, and one had no answer and the other had a junk answer that should've been a comment.

Basically what I'm looking for is for someone that has some amount of experience developing for the mobile web to give me some possible avenues to travel down to solve this thing the right way. I don't want a hacky solution and I'm not necessarily looking for you to tell me what code to write. I just want to get to the bottom of what would cause the page to jerk like that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried adding a meta viewport element to the `head`?

Comment: I don't believe there is. Adding one does not fix the issue, as I just tested.

Comment: Can we see the page in question or a jsfiddle? If the problem is repeatable then maybe someone could help